# Build applications for both Windows 7 and Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

I've built an application that makes use of C++11 features and the winsocket. 
I built the application using windows 10 and the Visual C++ 2015 compiler. 
On the Win10 machine it runs fine. On a Win7 machine a popup shows up, stating that the file ucrtbase.dll is missing.

I've done a little research on the web and found out that Microsoft did quite a big change to the CRT and thus renamed some dlls. These dlls are not available per se on Win7.

Is there a way to build my application independant from this libraries? I'd like to ship the application to both Win7 and Win10 users.

Thank you

Comment: Using the static library option (/MT instead of /MD, it's one of the project settings) will fix some, but perhaps not all of these issues. I don't recall if the CRT library can be statically linked. I seem to recall something like kernel32.dll is not statically linked (even with /MT option).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the comment on your question says, you can statically link the CRT by using the /MT flag in project's `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library` setting.

If this is not an option for your project, you can install the CRT redistributables instead.

In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\1033` you will find three files:

- `vcredist_arm.exe`
- `vcredist_x64.exe`
- `vcredist_x86.exe`

These are packages containing the CRT for this version of Visual Studio, designed to be installed on machines that need to run your software.

Install the appropriate redistributable on the target system prior to running your application. For example, if your application is 32bit, install `vcredist_x86.exe`. For 64bit, install `vcredist_x64.exe`.

Generally when you create an installer for your software you bundle these files too, and run them during the install process.

Comment: Thank you, the /MT flag did the trick. For cmake it is done via if (MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
endif()

Comment: Don't forget to update the CMAKE_C_FLAGS_* too if your solution involves C projects. I ran into that quite recently ;)